# How to get a new Iterable for every call on Stateless EJB

Tags: java, ejb, stateless-session-bean

I'm querying a DB in this EJB. Result is Iterable (I can't change that).

But since the EJB is @Stateless it will "reuse" the Iterable<>, and the query result just gets added to it. Instead of being a "new" one!

How could i avoid that ?

I don't know if there a "fix" on the Iterable or is there something to be done with the SessionBean? Is this a bad combination?

```
@Stateless
public class StartSessionBean implements Serializable, StartSessionBeanLocal {
...
public Iterable<VType> resultQuery;
...
    public List<VType> queryThis(String this) {
...
        resultQuery = (Iterable<Type>) "query DB";
        //Do Things here
        return something;
    }
}
```

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something, but why not just move the resultQuery declaration to queryThis() method?

Comment: No you are right! But is this the only way to make an Iterable work in a stateless EJB?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot maintain state such as `public Iterable<VType> resultQuery;` in a stateless session bean. That is what "stateless" means.

In practice what actually happens varies from implementation to implementation. Some will give you a brand new bean each time you call it. Others will select one from a pool and give you that one, with the result that each client may get another's instance of `resultQuery`.

If you want to maintain state in the EJB then you must use a [@Stateful](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ejb/Stateful.html) session bean.

Edit: You should not need to maintain the resultQuery field anyway. Just make it a local in your method implementation. Presumably you're using it in a for-each loop as that is what they're for.

Comment: Yes, I was guessing stateless is the option. Then maybe with @Remove to save some memory. But maybe you know about another strategy to deal with Iterable in a stateless session bean, some keywords to research for me? It should save some resources since its a simple application and hopefully only use little compute resources.